# AngularJS md-autocomplete return all possible substrings

Tags: angularjs, search, angular-material

I'm using [md-autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) to let users search through subjects at my university.

The **problem** is my search function only searches sequentially (left to right) through each display value.

**For example:**  If I search "Arts and Architecture" I get "no results found", which I do not want to happen.

I would like "Arts and Architecture" to return a result.

The subjects are in this format:

```
$scope.subjects = [
  {
    value: 'AA',
    display: 'AA - Arts and Architecture'
  },
  {
    value: 'AAAS',
    display: 'AAAS - African/Afr Amer Studies'
  },
  {
    value: 'ABA',
    display: 'ABA - Applied Behavior Analysis'
  },
  {
    value: 'ABE',
    display: 'ABE - Ag and Biological Engineering'
  }
]
```

Here is my search method:

```
$scope.searchQuery = function(text) {
  text = text.toUpperCase();
  var result = $scope.subjects.filter(function(item) {
    return item.display.includes(text);
  });
  return result;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<md-autocomplete 
   md-selected-item="selectedItem"
   md-search-text="searchText" 
   md-items="item in searchQuery(searchText)" 
   md-item-text="item.display" 
   md-min-length="0" 
   placeholder="Select a subject">
  <md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
  </md-item-template>
  <md-not-found>
    No matches found.
  </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

This is due to case sensitivity, i.e. you're actually doing the equivalent of...

```
"Arts and Architecture".includes("ARTS AND ARCHITECTURE"); // false
```

...and because [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is case sensitive, it returns `false`. It just so happened to work at the beginning of your string because all of the letters are uppercase and the input too was uppercase:

```
"AA".includes("AA"); // true (fluke!)
```

**Solution**

If you make `item.display` and `text` both uppercase it should work:

```
$scope.searchQuery = function(text) {
  var result = $scope.subjects.filter(function(item) {
    return item.display.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase());
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: No problem, you could always upvote instead! Pleased it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation JS method `str.includes(searchString[, position])` states:

> Params: position -> Optional. The position within the string at which to begin searching
>   for searchString.(defaults to 0).

so your code is starting from index 0.

How about using indexOf instead ? changing this line: `return item.display.includes(text);`

to `return item.display.indexOf(text) !== -1;`

Answer (score 0):

"includes" function checks only if searched string exists in target string or not. For md-autocomplete to work, you need to match those objects from the array which contains your searched text or part of searched text. Modify your code to:

```
$scope.searchQuery = function(text) {
    var result = $scope.subjects.filter(function(item) {
       if (item.display.toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) >-1)
          return item;
});
    return result;
}
```